# Sending emails on behalf of user

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

So im implementing a mailservice in our webapp that users can utilize to send out emails to persons on a certain list. Now i need to know how to best use the System.Net.Mail object to send mail on the users behalf. Ive been trying this now for a while without the right results.

I would like the mail to read "our system on behalf of user 1" and the reply to adress should be the adress that user1 has in our system so that when the contacted person wants to reply to the mail he should get user1:s address, not ours. How can I do this?

Which fields do I need to declare and how? This is how i have it set up right now, but a reply to these settings sends a mail back to noreply@oursystem.com

```
from = 'noreply@oursystem.com'
replyTo = 'user1@privateaddress.com'
to = 'user1@privateaddress.com'
sender  = 'user1@privateaddress.com'
cc  = ''
```

Comment: "sender" must actually be "noreply@oursystem.com" while from is the private address from the user. SPF & DKIM are verifying the "sender" while the reply to address will be the one from "from" (unless the replytolist is configured).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a programming error on the receiving end. The correct solution is to set the from and replyto as above. That will get the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**ReplyTo** is `obsolete`. You should use **ReplyToList**

Example:

```
MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("noreply@oursystem.com");
MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("user1@privateaddress.com");
MailAddress mailReplyTo = new MailAddress("user1@privateaddress.com");

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = mailFrom;
message.To.Add(mailTo); //here you could add multiple recepients
message.ReplyToList.Add(mailReplyTo); //here you could add multiple replyTo adresses
```

Comment: Im using .net 2.0 it doesnt seem to have replytolist?

Comment: Ah then it's ok. I've check it with .net 4.0. There were major changes in MailMessage between 3.5 and 4.0.

Comment: does this satisfy the requirement:  I would like the mail to read "our system on behalf of user 1"